# Reconcile two lists

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, iterator

So I have two different lists, with different formats and structure that need to be reconciled.  Essentially, set B needs to match what's in set A, but I want to preserve the state of the existing items in set B and not overwrite them with what's in set A.

For reference, list doesn't actually mean list.  The "lists" come in a couple of different forms from straight arrays to maps.  All use standard iterators to access elements.

The way I typically handle is like so...

```
for item in listA
  if listB contains item
     mark item in list B as visited
  else 
     add item to list b

 for item in listB
   if visited is true
      continue
   else
       add item to removeList

 for item in removeList
    remove item from list B
```

This works and is the only real way I can think of to do it.  I don't like how many iterations I have to do though, having the three for loops back to back feels wrong.  However, since I'm using iterators I can't remove anything from the lists while I'm checking them and instead have to add them to the third remove list.

In potential answers please keep in mind that speed and memory footprint are more important to me than how easy it is to write the code.

My question really boils down to this -- is there a better way to do this that I'm not thinking of?

I'm in C++/C FWIW, though I think any solution will probably be language agnostic.

Thanks!

Comment: Hopefully "contains" is a constant or at least ln time op.  Any reason you cannot remove the item in list B immediately instead of marking as (not) visited and then iterating again to kill it?  With a little work, I'm sure the iterators could handle this right?

Comment: That was my main concern.  My understanding of the STL iterators was that the underlying data structure cannot be touched (in terms of removals or inserts) while it was being iterated over.  Any "fix" for that I can think of would be more expensive than iterating over the remove list -- which in the general case will be very small.

Comment: I believe that when calling "remove" on an STL container, it gives you a new iterator that you can use to continue with your transversal.  Try that to see if things speed up.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do it that may be more efficient:

```
removeList = listB

for item in listA
  if listB contains item
    remove item from removeList
  else
    add item to listB

for item in removeList
  remove item from listB
```

So instead of building up the removeList from nothing, it starts off with everything and then has items removed from it.

You could also make this more efficient by having the removeList store indexes rather than the actual items. As long as items are added to the end of listB in the initial loop, and items are removed in reverse order, the indexes should still be valid.

In fact it's even simpler if you replace the *removeList* with a boolean array of items to keep. So the algorithm becomes something like this:

```
initialise all itemsToKeep to false
savedListLength = length of listB

for item in listA
  offset = find item in listB
  if found
    mark itemsToKeep[offset] as true
  else
    add item to listB

for offset from savedListLength-1 down to 0
  if itemsToKeep[offset] is false
    remove the offset from listB
```

This avoids the need to copy anything into the *removeList* initially. And the expense of the *itemsToKeep* array is surely no worse than whatever you are using to keep track of the visted items in your algorithm.

To some extent the most suitable algorithm maybe depend on the form of the lists (i.e. vectors, or linked lists, etc.) But I do think my approach has the potential to be more effecient either way.

Comment: How is that better than what I have though?  Copying list b to removelist is going to cause an iteration of list B, you have to iterate A and the remove list still, so all told you're still looking at the same number of iterations.

Comment: @MotieMediator That's a fair point, but in terms of lines of code it is neater, which counts for something. And it doesn't require marking anything which I think is also a plus.

Comment: @MotieMediator Have also updated the answer to show how my algorithm can be modified to get rid of the removeList altogether.